# How can I group different series by different units using rangeSelector?

Tags: highcharts

So my problem is I have 3 series each with 30min interval data.

1. The data series:

   - should be grouped by units defined in the rangeSelector text ( this is working fine )
2. The Average serie:

   - should be grouped by a unit greater then the data series ( like data grouped by day the average should show the week average, data grouped by week the average should be the month average )
3. The Peak series:

   - should be grouped by a unit greater then the data series ( like data grouped by day the peak should show the week peak, data grouped by week the peak should be the month peak )

The average and peak series don't need to have value every 30min if it helps solving the problem. but it should be a strait line for the period so I cannot have one point for each grouping.

this is an example of what I have now (http://jsfiddle.net/tc97kud0/11/)

`rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [
        {
          type: "day",
          count: 1,
          text: "Day"
        }, {
          type: "week",
          count: 1,
          text: "Week",
          dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [ [ "day", [ 1 ] ] ]
          }
        }, {
          type: "month",
          count: 1,
          text: "Month ( group by day )",
          dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [ [ "day", [ 1 ] ] ]
          }
        }, {
          type: "month",
          count: 1,
          text: "Month ( group by week )",
          dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [ [ "week", [ 1 ] ] ]
          }
        }, {
          type: "year",
          count: 1,
          text: "Year",
          dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [ [ "month", [ 1 ] ] ]
          }
        }, {
          type: "all",
          text: "All"
        }
      ],
      selected: 5,
      buttonTheme: {
        width: null
      }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: "average"
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Data point count (confidence)',
        data: ADBE,
        type: 'column',
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: "SUM"
        }
    }]`

So is there any way I can change grouping by rangeSelector and have different units for grouping to each series?

I know that I can have different approximation for each series setting it in the serie dataGrouping property.

But the units are based on rangeSelector options, so I cannot or don't know how to set the units in the serie to be used accordingly to the rangeSelector option active at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `click` events of range selector buttons to set individual data grouping for every series:

```
       {
          type: "month",
          count: 1,
          text: "Month ( group by day )",
          events: {
            click: function() {
                chart.series[0].update({
                  dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [ [ "day", [ 1 ] ] ]
                      }
              }, false);

              chart.series[1].update({
                  dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [ [ "month", [1] ] ]
                      }     
              }, false);

            }
          }
        }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xfyuawmu/

Comment: Thank you!
I did`n think of that. Was over complicating the problem.